# Why is custom Splash.png throwing a XML extension error

Tags: xml, android-studio, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I replaced the default splash.png images in the res/drawable folders with custom images which were named 'splash.png'.

However the build fails with the exception:

> The file name must end with xml

This is thrown for the splash.png file in res/drawable-port-xhdpi.

The original file in /drawable-port-xhdpi had same name and extension, splash.png, as the current imported file, so I don't know what the issue is here.

This is the project folder view :
[image]

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to the way android-studio handles rescources. If you want to include the picture in your app, you would have to add it to the `drawable` folder and android would automatically generate the correct alternate version of it, in the other drawable folders like your `drawable-port-xhdpi`. If you just go to drawable and add your image there (and if the file type is supported, sometimes png can be in some wierd color setting), then you will be able to add that to your app.

Also, it can be that the project you are trying to build needs to have an `.xml` as a splash image. Then you would have to get a vector graphic `.svg` of your image and add a Image Rescource via `New>Vector Asset` in the `Project Window`. Then your problem should be fine.

EDIT:

If you want to create an xml, just go to `New>VectorAsset` .Then your `.svg` file will be converted to `.xml`. If that doesnt work. Try getting back the old state with all the old splash images and without the error. Then try to find all old Splash images and replace them one by one with the excact same name.

Comment: So if I want to replace the default splash.png do I delete the current splash.png in drawable and import another splash.png then all drawable folders will be automatically updated? Tried that doesn't seem to of happened. Also, created .svg just in case but couldnt  find a the menu option New-Image Resource..Only New - Image Asset- but not sure where I save this

Comment: I changed the answer to try and clarify the solution.

Comment: thanks- step 1 did not work, can't revert to original splash.png images so step 2 option is out, Istep 3 - I've tried two websites to convert my png to svg - first website throws numerous  errors created to 'commas  in android studio https://www.pngtosvg.com , this website just hangs https://www.autotracer.org . do u know a good on line tool for converting pngs to svg compatible with studio?

Comment: Done - tried replacing splash.png with splash.xml in Drawable- instead of deleting splash.png i changed name to splash3.png, error now is still the same except it refers to splash3,png. So changing to svg doesn't appear too worked, do you know here it is defined the name / location of the file to be used for a splash screen?

Comment: Just had a thought-  could this be referring to the png in the 'Splash' folder? What purpose does this folder have?

Comment: Very intresting, are you rinning basic android-studio? I can not replicate any Splash folder Errors because I do not have a Splash folder... What version are you running and could you provide more detail on how you got that folder?

Comment: It’s a ionic capacitor app, perhaps the splash folder is unique for this, I followed the these instructions which were referenced directly from capacitor docs - https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-icons-splash-screens-launch-images-to-capacitor-projects/

Comment: Can you search in your android studio project, where your capacitor project refrences the splash screen? Because this error should not be there if you *excactly* replaced all the files in the folders, you could also try and open them with the explorer, to see if you did this correctly....

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the 'Splash' folder in a new project, nor existing capacitor project, I imported the splash.xml but errors were thrown, eventually I removed all folder contents, cleaned - build- and it runs fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235869/discussion-between-timblocker-and-dancingbush).